# Apply custom In Between Filter for PrimeNG: Datatable

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

Consider a scenario where I am displaying a START and END YEARs in a `p-dataTable` column.

Here is the column code snippet:

```
<p-column field="startYear" header="Active Period" filterPlaceholder="Search" [filter]="true">
  <ng-template let-col let-manual="rowData" pTemplate="body">
    {{record.startYear}} - {{record.endYear}}
  </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

Which displays as:

```
|--------------|
| ActivePeriod |
|--------------|
|2015 - 2017   |
|--------------|
|2012 - 2016   |
|--------------|
|2023 - 2025   |
|--------------|
|2024 - 2030   |
|--------------|
|2011 - 2013   |
|--------------|
```

I want to apply a custom filter so that when user types in an YEAR the table should only show the records which falls in that Active period.

Which means I have to write a logic where I have check if the user searched year is in between each active period.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

First, you can add hidden assistant field `years` which will contain an array with years within given range, so for range `2012 - 2015`, we will get an array:

```
[
  2012,
  2013,
  2014,
  2015
]
```

You can do it using `map` function, something like:

```
const yearsRange = row.endYear - row.startYear + 1;
YOUR_DATA_ARRAY.map(row => ({
  ...row,
  years: [...Array(yearsRange).keys()].map(y => y + row.startYear)
}))
```

Out of the box `PRIME NG` does not have `between` filter. [Filters available currently](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/table/table.ts#L1088) are:

- startsWith
- contains
- endsWith
- equals
- notEquals
- in
- lt
- gt

You can extend it writing your own filter:

```
// import Table class
import { Table } from 'primeng/components/table/table';

.....

// get reference to your table
@ViewChild('dt') tableRef: Table;

.....

// extend filters
this.tableRef.filterConstraints.between = (value, filter: any): boolean => {
  if (filter === undefined || filter === null || filter === '') {
    return true;
  }

  if (value === undefined || value === null || !value.length) {
    return false;
  }

  return value.some(val => +val === +filter);
};
```

now you can use it in your HTML:

```
<p-table #dt [value]="cars">

  .....

  <input size="4"
         (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, 'years', 'between')">

  .....
```

STACKBLITZ: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sfoh3j?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

**UPDATE**

I noticed you use old (and deprecated) `DataTable`, 
the solution should be very similar, [filters](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/datatable/datatable.ts#L1833) are almost the same missing `lt` and `gt`. Just change names in imports and type names in my example. HTML syntax is also different.
Let me know if you need help with old `DataTable`

Comment: hi @Andriy, I'm using the old version DataTable and I'm getting an error on the .filterConstraints could you please help me? I have no time to migrate to the newer version. thanks in advance.

Comment: please create a STACKBLITZ repro of your issue, explain what is the error and  what you want to achieve and I will try to help

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Andriy helped me out on a particular problem I was having with the DataTable. We needed a couple of custom filters for >= and <= for floats. I took Andriy's solution and applied it to our problem. I'm posting the code here in case anyone else can benefit from the combined responses.

1 - Built a custom component to handle the input from the user

Typescript:

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter  } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, AbstractControl, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { SelectItem } from 'primeng/components/common/selectitem';
import { ICustomGtLsFilter } from '../../Models/ICustomGtLsFilter';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-filter',
  templateUrl: './custom-filter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-filter.component.css']
})
export class CustomFilterComponent {
    @Output() onCriteriaSelectedChanged = new EventEmitter<ICustomGtLsFilter>();

    _myForm: FormGroup;
    _criteria: SelectItem[] = [{label: 'None', value: 'none'}, { label: '<=', value: 'lte' }, { label: '>=', value: 'gte' }];

    private _filterModel: ICustomGtLsFilter = new ICustomGtLsFilter();

    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
        this._myForm = _fb.group({
            _inputField: [null],
            _criteriaSel:[]
        });
    }

    fieldChanged(event) {
        // clear the input field
        if (event === "none") {
            this._myForm.controls['_inputField'].setValue('');
        }

        this._filterModel.Criteria = event;
        this._filterModel.FilterVal = this._myForm.controls['_inputField'].value;

        this.onCriteriaSelectedChanged.emit(this._filterModel);
    }
}
```

Template

```
<form [formGroup]="_myForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="number" name="_inputField" id="_inputField" [formControl]="_myForm.controls['_inputField']" autocomplete="off" />
            <p-dropdown [options]="_criteria"
                        [autoWidth]="false"
                        id="_criteriaSel"
                        name="_criteriaSel"
                        placeholder="None"
                        formControlName="_criteriaSel"
                        (onChange)="fieldChanged($event.value)">
            </p-dropdown>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Interface:

```
export class ICustomGtLsFilter {
    FilterVal: number;
    Criteria: string;
}
```

Here is the custom component defined as an ng-template for the column we want to apply the filter to:

```
<p-column field='TimeRem'
                  header='Time Remaining'
                  [sortable]='true'
                  [filter]='true'>
            <ng-template let-col
                         pTemplate='filter'>
                <app-custom-filter appendTo="body" 
                         (onCriteriaSelectedChanged)="dt.filter($event.FilterVal,col.field,$event.Criteria)">
                </app-custom-filter>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template let-col
                         let-rd='rowData'
                         pTemplate='body'>
                <span appAlignRightStyle>{{rd[col.field] | format: '0.0'}}</span>
            </ng-template>
        </p-column>
```

And finally the relevant typescript code in the component that uses the DataTable:

...

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomFilterComponent } from '../../../../shared/custom-filter/custom-filter.component';
import { ICustomGtLsFilter } from '../../../../Models/ICustomGtLsFilter';

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('dt') dt: DataTable;

 ngAfterViewInit() { 
        // custom filter implementations
        this.dt.filterConstraints['gte'] = function gte(value: any, filter: any): boolean {

            if (filter === undefined || filter === null) {
                return false;
            }

            if (value === undefined || value === null || value.length === 0) {
                return false;
            }

            if (value >= filter) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        };

        this.dt.filterConstraints['lte'] = function lte(value: any, filter: any): boolean {

            if (filter === undefined || filter === null) {
                return false;
            }

            if (value === undefined || value === null || value.length === 0) {
                return false;
            }

            if (value <= filter) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        };

        this.dt.filterConstraints['none'] = function none(value: any, filter: any): boolean {

            return true;
        };

    }
```