# Issue: PrimeNG Datatable Column Filter does not match to piped altered data in the field

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

[updated]
**The issue is when using the PrimeNG Column Filter to search it does not match to what is being displayed but matches to the original value.**

As an example I'm using longitude and latitude values where the raw format would be something like the following for their values

- 00.123456
- 01.123456
- 012.34567

Display values would be to cut off leading zeros mostly and trim the total length of digits to 5

- 0.1234
- 1.1234
- 12.345

Issue: Performing a Column filter 'Starts With' of 12 in order to match to the visible value of 12.3456 does not find anything because the record data passed in is 012.34567. Same issue with 'Ends With'.

Issue: To find the match you would need to know the raw format of 012.34567 and perform a Column filter 'Starts With' search of of 012 in order to match to the visible value of 12.3456. This makes no sense.

I found GitHub Issue posts on this from years back but nothing within the last few years.

*** Is there a way around this to fix the filter ability? ***

OR

*** Do you have a better solution that this component can do easily? ***

Closest post I could find dealing with different filtering on values displayed was [Apply custom In Between Filter for PrimeNG: Datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229978/apply-custom-in-between-filter-for-primeng-datatable)

*** UPDATED 06/08/2022 ***

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-filterservice-demo-617tfw?file=src/app/app.component.ts) which uses a datatable with car data.

The car data contains a VIN where I modified the values to be prefixed with 'xx'.

The display filters off the 'xx'.

You can search the column for what is viewed and match it to the raw data.

How can I modify the built in options for Filtering to use my filter instead of specific built in ones.

For example, I want to replace the built in 'Starts With' and 'Ends With' filter options with my own functionality but KEEP all the other built in options.

Comment: See update: I found a way of creating a custom filter which I can use to account for rules applied to values and how they display. The example I found and modified. In particular I modified the VIN value to all contain in the raw data 'xx' in the front of the values. The Filter on the column accounts for that and allows the user to search on what they see.

Comment: What I need now is a way to customize / replace some of the built in Filter types and keep others.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution. See my [StackBlitz Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-filterservice-demo-617tfw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

You would need to adjust the file: app.component.ts section

`this.filterService.register(customFilterName, (value, filter): boolean => {...`

to implement custom filter searches you are looking to perform such as accounting for prefixed values that are cut from the display or if you wanted to search an object that was transformed to a readable value such as a date object.